# When does bash rehash the PATH?

Tags: bash

Under what circumstances is the `PATH` rehashed in bash? I can't figure out when it's necessary to call `hash -r` and when it happens automatically. The best I can figure out is that the PATH is rehashed whenever a command is typed that isn't found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

bash does not hash all contents of `PATH`. It only has a hashtable of commands that were *used* during this session (aka in this shell process). For example:

```
$ hash
hits    command
   1    /home/grawity/code/bin/todo
$ ls
boot/ dev/ etc/ home/ usr/ ...
$ hash
hits    command
   1    /usr/bin/ls
   1    /home/grawity/code/bin/todo
```

So `hash -r` is only necessary if you *used* a program at least once in the current shell, and later moved it elsewhere.

Comment: OK, that clarifies things a bit, though I still don't get when rehashing happens automatically.

Comment: @asmeurer: as far as I know, bash never automatically rehashes unless shell option `checkhash` is set and the hashed filename no longer exists. (And then it only rehashes the one name, not the whole hash.)

Comment: I see now. So `hash -r` doesn't *rehash*, it just *clears* the hash.